# How to declare array elements volatile in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, concurrency, volatile

Is there a way to declare array elements `volatile` in Java? I.e.

```
volatile int[] a = new int[10];
```

declares the *array reference* `volatile`, but the *array elements* (e.g. `a[1]`) are still not volatile. So I'm looking for something like

```
volatile int[] a = new volatile int[10];
```

but it doesn't work that way. Is it possible at all?

Comment: @Kanagavelu Sugumar: AtomicReference _is_ a wrapped `volatile`, with some extra methods (getAndSet etc.).

Comment: Yes you can make array volatile. Please refer this - http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/10/133-java-interview-questions-answers-from-last-5-years.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `AtomicIntegerArray` or `AtomicLongArray` or `AtomicReferenceArray`

The `AtomicIntegerArray` class implements an int array whose individual fields can be accessed with volatile semantics, via the class's `get()` and `set()` methods. Calling `arr.set(x, y)` from one thread will then guarantee that another thread calling `arr.get(x)` will read the value y (until another value is read to position x).

See:

- [AtomicIntegerArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html)
- [AtomicLongArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLongArray.html)
- [AtomicReferenceArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html)
- [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) Package Summary

Comment: I wonder why there are specific `AtomicArrays` for int and long, but not for other primitive types... But of course the rest of the primitives could be faked by using their wrappers in an `AtomicReferenceArray`.

Comment: I think AtomicIntegerArray and AtomicLongArray are optimized to work with integer and long respectively.

Comment: @JoonasPulakka for other primitive types you can also convert them to int or long using e.g. `Float.floatToIntBits(float)`. This avoids the need of boxing when using `AtomicReferenceArray`.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't make array elements volatile. See also http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html .

Comment: Actually you can, but with additional efforts.

Comment: Technically that's still not making the elements volatile, but the array operations are volatile.  Since `int` for this case is a primitive, it essentially has the same behavior, but this could not be easily extended for non-primitive arrays.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this is using the JDK 9+ [`VarHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html) class. As you can see in the source code of the `Atomic`*xxx*`Array` classes like [`AtomicIntegerArray`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.java), these classes also use `VarHandle` since JDK 9:

```
//[...]

private static final VarHandle AA
    = MethodHandles.arrayElementVarHandle(int[].class);
private final int[] array;

//[...]

/**
 * Returns the current value of the element at index {@code i},
 * with memory effects as specified by {@link VarHandle#getVolatile}.
 *
 * @param i the index
 * @return the current value
 */
public final int get(int i) {
    return (int)AA.getVolatile(array, i);
}

/**
 * Sets the element at index {@code i} to {@code newValue},
 * with memory effects as specified by {@link VarHandle#setVolatile}.
 *
 * @param i the index
 * @param newValue the new value
 */
public final void set(int i, int newValue) {
    AA.setVolatile(array, i, newValue);
}

//[...]
```

You first create a `VarHandle` like this:

```
MethodHandles.arrayElementVarHandle(yourArrayClass)
```

For example, you can enter `byte[].class` here to implement the missing `AtomicByteArray` yourself.

And then you can access it using the `set`*xxx*`(array, index, value)` and `get`*xxx*`(array, index)` methods, where `array` is of type `yourArrayClass`, `index` is of type `int`, `value` is of the type of an element in your array (`yourArrayClass.getComponentType()`).

Note that if, for example, `yourArrayClass == byte[].class` but you enter `42` as `value`, you get an error because `42` is an `int` instead of a `byte` and the parameters of the access methods are vararg `Object...` parameters:

```
java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert MethodHandle(VarHandle,byte[],int,byte)void to (VarHandle,byte[],int,int)void
```

(The second signature is the one that you used, the first one is the one that you should have used.)

---

Note that in JDK 8 and below [`sun.misc.Unsafe`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/jdk.unsupported/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java) was used to implement the atomic classes like [`AtomicIntegerArray`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.java):

```
//[...]

private static final Unsafe unsafe = Unsafe.getUnsafe();
private static final int base = unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(int[].class);
private static final int shift;
private final int[] array;

static {
    int scale = unsafe.arrayIndexScale(int[].class);
    if ((scale & (scale - 1)) != 0)
        throw new Error("data type scale not a power of two");
    shift = 31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(scale);
}

private long checkedByteOffset(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= array.length)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index " + i);

    return byteOffset(i);
}

private static long byteOffset(int i) {
    return ((long) i << shift) + base;
}

//[...]

/**
 * Gets the current value at position {@code i}.
 *
 * @param i the index
 * @return the current value
 */
public final int get(int i) {
    return getRaw(checkedByteOffset(i));
}

private int getRaw(long offset) {
    return unsafe.getIntVolatile(array, offset);
}

/**
 * Sets the element at position {@code i} to the given value.
 *
 * @param i the index
 * @param newValue the new value
 */
public final void set(int i, int newValue) {
    unsafe.putIntVolatile(array, checkedByteOffset(i), newValue);
}

//[...]
```

Using `Unsafe` is still an option (although I think it's a bit tricky to obtain an instance), but it is discouraged because you have to check array bounds yourself and it might segfault the Java process if you make a mistake, while `VarHandle` does bounds checks for you and throws a Java exception if the given index is out of bounds (but that may come with a performance cost). Besides that, `Unsafe` is not officially supported and might be removed at any time.

But as of JDK 10 `Unsafe` is still used in [`AtomicInteger`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java) because of *'unresolved cyclic startup dependencies'*.

---

If you want to know more about the different get and set methods available, take a look at [Using JDK 9 Memory Order Modes](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm) (I have to say that I'm not an expert in this at all (yet?)).

---

<s>Note that as of today you cannot use `VarHandle` in Kotlin, because it wraps the vararg `Object...` parameters of the get and set methods in an `Object[]`, see [bug KT-26165](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26165):</s>

```
java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert MethodHandle(VarHandle,byte[],int,byte)void to (VarHandle,Object[])void
```

*(should be fixed now)*

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
static class Cell<T> {
        volatile T elem;
    }

private Cell<T>[] alloc(int size){
        Cell<T>[] cells = (Cell<T>[]) (new Cell[size]);
        return cells;
    }

 volatile Cell<T>[] arr;
 Cell<T>[] newarr = alloc(16);
 for (int i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++) {
      newarr[i] = new Cell<>();
 }
 arr = newarr;
```

the cells make the content volatile too. also I assign the new array to the volatile one only after pre allocating the cells... there's the trade off of the Cell extra memory, but it's manageable